# What does the -g option for npm install and npm list do?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

The Node.js `npm` (Node Package Manager) has a `-g` command line argument, which I often see referenced. For example, the documentation for the [Microsoft Azure x-plat (cross-platform) CLI tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli) says to install it by using `npm install -g azure-cli`.

Question: What does the `-g` option do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What options do I have to install node modules?

**After writing this I quickly found and old but still [applicable post](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) by Isaac (yes, the npm @isaacs). But I still think the below post is informational.**

You can install `npm` modules **`globally`** or **`locally`** - you already know that, but why?

1. **Globally:** `npm install -g some-module-a`: This module is intended to be used as an executable (i.e. CLI, file watcher, code minifier, logger, etc.).
2. **Locally:** `npm install some-module-b`: To be imported and used in your app via import, `var someModule = require('some-module)`

`global` modules are one of the best ideas of `npm`. We can easily create executables using `node/javascript`. If your node app is meant to be run as an executable, then you will want others to install it `globally`. If it's a utility, helper, application, etc. then you usually don't want it installed globally. So, unless the module explicitly states that you should install it with `-g`, then don't.

**One more time**: if you are wanting to use some module called `some-module` in your node app - `var someModule = require('some-module')`, then `npm install some-module` from the root of your node app to pull it into your local `node_modules` directory. If you've installed `some-module` globally and not locally, it will usually *not* load and will show you an error about not finding the module (even though it can be made to load the global module - hint: [just don't!](https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.0.0/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders))

### So what exactly happens when you install `globally`?

`npm install -g [some module]` installs the specified node module in a directory higher up in your file system (i.e. usually `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in unix systems). The biggest use case for global modules is for `CLI`s written using node (think `npm`, `bower`, `gulp`, `grunt`, et. al.).

Let's look at what happens when you install `bower` globally:
***follow these steps in your command line/terminal**

**step**: `npm install -g bower`
**explanation**: the module - all of it's files and dependencies - are saved in your global directory (e.g. /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower).

Something else happened here. Somehow you can now run `bower` in your command line. Awesome!

**step**: `bower -v` --> results in the installed bower version (i.e. `1.6.5`)
**explanation**: It's now a fully executable node app using `bower` as the keyword. Inside `bower`'s [`package.json`](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/package.json#L135) file you'll find a `bin` property:

```
"bin": {
    "bower": "bin/bower"
}
```

### So how did that all work?

`npm` will create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from where most executables live, `/usr/local/bin/bower` over to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower`, where the module lives. That symlink makes it so when the executable runs, it can reference other files in the original module, including it's local `node_modules`. Pretty cool, huh?

***Note on executables**: If you create a file called `awesomeness` in `/usr/local/bin/` and `chmod u+x` (user + executable) it. Then write some scripting in it (in this case javascript using `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top). Then you can run it anywhere in your command line/terminal just by typing `awesomeness`.

Hope that helped. I know doing a deeper dive into it helped me early on.

Comment: It should be noted that it is fine to install executables locally as well, see `eslint`, `browserify`, `grunt-cli`, `xo`, etc. Or maybe you are just not sure whether you'd like the executable in the first place — then you can install it locally and try.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js packages can be installed one of two ways:

- Globally
- Locally

The `-g` option instructs `npm` to install the package globally. You would install a Node.js package globally, if you want to be able to call the command directly from the terminal.

From [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally):

> There are two ways to install npm packages: locally or globally. You choose which kind of installation to use based on how you want to use the package.
>
> If you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you can want to install it globally. On the other hand, if you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's require, then you want to install locally.
>
> To download packages globally, you simply use the command npm install -g , e.g.: